# Applying Symbology To MXD Layers From Symbology Files In ArcGIS Stand Alone ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, error-000732

I have a saved `.mxd` map in directory called `Project.mxd` and some layer symbology files `.lyr`s inside a folder called `lyr`

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Data\Maps\Project.mxd")
lyrPath = "C:\Data\lyrs\"
```

How can I map the symbology of Layers inside the map to the layer symbology files `.lyr` on an stand alone ArcPy Script?

For Example if I have a layer called `Population` in the `Project.mxd` how can I apply its symbology from a file called `pop-2016.lyr` and so on?

[image]

I already tried to use this snippet

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Data\Maps\Project.mxd")
lyrPath = "C:\Data\lyrs\"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
 if lyr.name == "Population":
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Population", "C:\Data\lyrs\pop-2016.lyr")
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but I am getting this error

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR
>   000732: Input Layer: Dataset Population does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).